# Given a three-input Boolean function . f(a,b,c) = E(summation)m(0,1,2,3,7)

Tags: boolean, decoder

(a) Implement the function using a minimal network of 2:4 decoders and OR gates.

(b) Implement the function using a minimal network of 4:1 multiplexers.

(c) Implement the function using a minimal network of 2:1 multiplexers.

I need help thanks

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: Use a dual four-input multiplexer to implement each of the following pairs of functions with the fewest external gates.